# Refresh an updatepanel on buttonclick from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm using a Gridview that is using datasource & databinding. When i reload the page the gridview is updated but I want it to be on the buttonclick, but it's not working for me.

The gridview inside the updatepanel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upWall" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvWallPosts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
             CaptionAlign="NotSet" CellPadding="5">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Avsändare">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# GetSender((int)Eval("WallSender"))%>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inlägg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Post")%>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWall" runat="server" Height="105px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="227px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnWall" runat="server" Text="Posta" onclick="btnWall_Click" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void btnWall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.SendWallPost(con.GetId(Membership.GetUser().UserName), Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]), txtWall.Text); //This method is sending the post
        upWall.Update();
    }
```

So, I want the updatepanel to be updated on the ButtonClick, I don't want to reload the whole page to see the result

Comment: How are you reloading your page?

Comment: Are you sure click handler is fired?

Comment: Yes it's fired, because when I reload the page the panel is updated

Comment: I am still interested to know if you are reloading your page using code.

Comment: Abide Masaraure: No I'm not using any code to reload the page. Just using the browser to reload it. That's why I want to make this updatepanel work :)

Comment: Place breakpoint at upWall.Update() line and see if it was called.

Answer (score 9):

Since i don't see the button `btnWall`, i assume that it's outside of the `UpdatePanel`.
But you need to define an explicit trigger if you want to allow a control outside of an `UpdatePanel` to trigger a postback.

Therefore you can use an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upWall" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
         ....
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnWall" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `con.SendWallPost` does not throw an exception?

Comment: Yes, then the application should crash for me cause I have not inplemented any try/catch for the moment

Comment: @krillezzz: Since you're in an asynchronous postback, you would probably see the exception as javascript error which might be hidden or swallowed. Anyway, use the debugger to see if if succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

By default, partial-page updates are enabled  in an update panel because the default value of the EnablePartialRendering property of the ScriptManager control is true.Putting the button in the update panel is suffice to give you what you need since the button acts as an asynchronus postback control inside the panel.Then just add this line( gvWallospts.Databind()) after your update.Let me know how it goes.

```
protected void btnWall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.SendWallPost(con.GetId(Membership.GetUser().UserName), Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]), txtWall.Text); //This method is sending the post
    //upWall.Update();
    gvWallPosts.DataBind();
}
```

**Try setting up you markup like this**

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upWall" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvWallPosts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
         CaptionAlign="NotSet" CellPadding="5">
        <Columns>
    <asp:Templatefield>
   <asp:Button ID="btnWall" runat="server" Text="Posta" command="Edit" />
     </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Avsändare">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# GetSender((int)Eval("WallSender"))%>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>

                      <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("WallSender")%>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inlägg">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Post")%>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                   <EditItemTemplate>

                     <asp:TextBox  Text='<%# Bind("Post")%>'/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In your grid Row updating event

```
  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{


    con.SendWallPost(con.GetId(Membership.GetUser().UserName),    Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]), txtWall.Text); 
     gvWallPosts.DataBind();


}
```

Make sure that also you Binding code in page load is sandwiched by this

```
 If(!IsPostBack)
     {
                   }
```

Comment: When I use gvWallPosts.DataBind() without declaring the whole gridview disappears. But if i use gvWallPosts.Datasource again the whole page is reloaded, not just the updatepanel

Comment: Where are you binding your datagridveiw. Is it in the page Load

Comment: I will update my post illustrating the use of an edit item template that will take away your misery. Item templates were never meant for editing records.

Comment: Bind will take the contents of the text box and map them back to the underlying data source.

Comment: I have updated the answer.To get rid of that error assign the bound values  it as textbox values

Comment: I get the error:  A call to Bind must be assigned to a property of a control inside a template. At the line with <asp:Textbox Text="<%#  Bind("WallPost") %>" />

Comment: My bad.Sorry for that.They need to be single quotes

Comment: <asp:Textbox Text='<%# Bind("WallPost") %>' />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22524/discussion-between-abide-masaraure-and-krillezzz)

Answer (score 0):

You should either put the button inside the update panel or define an explicit trigger to update the update panel on button click event as suggested by Tim Schmelter.

Comment: I tried both now, but it wont update until I reload the whole page. Can it have anything to be with any attributes on the updatepanel, like UpdateMode?

Comment: Make sure that you are not having any javascript error. Try checking error console of your browser (in firefox). Most probable reasons are, conflicting javascripts. Update panel is updated using javascript (client side) so if you are having any error in javascript, it will cause issue. Further, client side validation (validator controls) can also prevent the panel from updating.

Comment: I would further suggest you using fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ . It will allow you to see what is actually happening. You should also check if it is making any request or not and if it is making a request, is it getting proper answer of it or not.

Comment: I'm not using any javascript except for the autogenereted .js-files in visual studio

Comment: Have you checked the error console ? Further you need not to update the update panel from code behind. It will automatically get updated. You can safely remove those lies.

Comment: You should remove upWall.Update(); from your code. There is no need to update the panel from your code.

Comment: I agree he just needs to call the databind  method of his gridview.