# Updating gridview outside the update panel from update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a grid view on a popup, this popup is not a part of update panel.
But the button which shows this popup is inside an upadtepanel.

Now the problem is that the grid is not reflecting the changes done in gridview.

When i removed the update panel then the grid view was updated fine.

Comment: Some code will be useful to get an answer, and not general speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Because any section you want to update must be in `UpdatePanel`.

> UpdatePanel controls work by specifying regions of a page that can be updated without refreshing the whole page.

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Updating anything from outside of the panel is not possible, but you can trigger the panel to be updated from codebehind. Check this solution:

[Refresh an Update Panel on buttonclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258034/refresh-an-updatepanel-on-buttonclick-from-code-behind)